# Laravel 3: Model function with $this->save() cause error with Eloquent update

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-3

I've spent far too long on this and it just isn't working, so I've given up and will rewrite it with a Fluent update method instead.

But I wanted to post it here and see if anyone else has encountered this before.

```
// TEST CONTROLLER
$user = User::find(29);
// This user has a related subscription but it's lacking all of the braintree data that I need 
// So as a fallback I need to make sure that if the braintree_customer_id column is empty
// then we query braintree with an email lookup for the customer
// and then fill in the missing data.

$data = $user->subscription->braintree_customer;
var_dump($data);

// SUBSCRIPTION MODEL
public function get_braintree_customer()
{
    $braintree_customer_id = $this->braintree_customer_id;
    if (empty($braintree_customer_id))
    {
        // IF THE CUSTOMER DOESN"T HAVE ID SET THEN CALL ANOTHER FUNCTION IN THE MODEL
        $data = $this->customer_from_braintree;
        return $data;
    }
    $data = Braintree_Customer::find($braintree_customer_id);
    return $data;
}
public function get_customer_from_braintree()
{
    $data = FALSE;
    $braintree_customer = Braintree_Customer::search(array(
        Braintree_CustomerSearch::email()->is($this->user->email),
        // Braintree_CustomerSearch::email()->is('bleugh@pixelapes.com'),
    ));
    if (!empty($braintree_customer->_ids))
    {
        $braintree_customer_id = $braintree_customer->_ids[0];
        $data = Braintree_Customer::find($braintree_customer_id);
        $braintree_subscription = $data->creditCards[0]->subscriptions[0];

            $this->braintree_customer_id = $data->id;
            $this->braintree_subscription_id = $braintree_subscription->id;
            $this->braintree_payment_method_token = $braintree_subscription->paymentMethodToken;
            $this->braintree_plan_id = $braintree_subscription->planId;
            $this->save();
    }
    return $data;
}}
// IF I TRY USING $this->save() I get this error
// Even though I haven't tried to create a new Subscription - just update the old one
    Unhandled Exception

    Message:

    SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'

    SQL: INSERT INTO `subscriptions` (`id`, `user_id`, `braintree_customer_id`, `braintree_subscription_id`, `braintree_payment_method_token`, `braintree_plan_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

    Bindings: array (
      0 => 2,
      1 => 29,
      2 => '6056122',
      3 => '',
      4 => '',
      5 => '',
      6 => '2013-10-15 06:32:21',
      7 => '2013-10-15 06:32:21',
    )


Location:

path\to\laravel\database\connection.php on line 263
Stack Trace:

#0 path\to\laravel\database\connection.php(183): Laravel\Database\Connection->execute('INSERT INTO `su...', Array)
#1 path\to\laravel\database\query.php(824): Laravel\Database\Connection->query('INSERT INTO `su...', Array)
#2 [internal function]: Laravel\Database\Query->insert_get_id(Array, 'id')
#3 path\to\laravel\database\eloquent\query.php(267): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 path\to\laravel\database\eloquent\model.php(402): Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Query->__call('insert_get_id', Array)
#5 path\to\laravel\database\eloquent\model.php(402): Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Query->insert_get_id(Array, 'id')
#6 path\to\application\models\subscription.php(53): Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Model->save()
#7 path\to\laravel\database\eloquent\model.php(697): Subscription->get_customer_from_braintree()
#8 path\to\application\models\subscription.php(70): Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Model->__get('customer_from_b...')
#9 path\to\laravel\database\eloquent\model.php(697): Subscription->get_braintree_customer()
#10 path\to\application\controllers\test.php(10): Laravel\Database\Eloquent\Model->__get('braintree_custo...')
#11 [internal function]: Test_Controller->action_index()
#12 path\to\laravel\routing\controller.php(325): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#13 path\to\laravel\routing\controller.php(285): Laravel\Routing\Controller->response('index', Array)
#14 path\to\laravel\routing\controller.php(165): Laravel\Routing\Controller->execute('index', Array)
#15 path\to\laravel\routing\route.php(153): Laravel\Routing\Controller::call('test@index', Array)
#16 path\to\laravel\routing\route.php(124): Laravel\Routing\Route->response()
#17 path\to\laravel\laravel.php(167): Laravel\Routing\Route->call()
#18 path\to\public\index.php(34): require('D:\Work\www\xam...')
#19 {main}
```

I've tried with every single Eloquent update method I can think of, I've tried directly using the set_attribute() function in the second model function, I've tried creating setters for each of the columns I want to update and calling those setters, but then the function succeeds but the row is NOT updated.

However if I try to manually run the setters in a test controller they work fine?!

I've tried calling the model function directly from a controller and it still causes an error.

The weirdest thing is that in my user model I have done this exact approach before where I set attributes on $this and then run $this->save(); and it works fine.

Baffled!

Comment: Using fluent I have no problems at all.

Comment: In your model have you overwritten the `__construct` method?

Comment: Sigh. Yes, yes I had.

Comment: Thanks David. If only I had come and read this an hour ago! Would have saved me more time!

Comment: no problem, this sounded remarkably familiar ;-) glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

As per David Barker's comment - I had overwritten the __construct()

I had to pull in the $attributes and $exists from the parent class.

This works now.

```
public function __construct($attributes = array(), $exists = false) {
    parent::__construct($attributes, $exists); // initialize the model according to the parent class functionality.
    require_once path('app').'libraries/braintree_php/lib/Braintree.php';
    Braintree_Configuration::environment(Config::get('braintree.environment'));
    Braintree_Configuration::merchantId(Config::get('braintree.merchant_id'));
    Braintree_Configuration::publicKey(Config::get('braintree.public_key'));
    Braintree_Configuration::privateKey(Config::get('braintree.private_key'));
}
```